# updating status on twitter from android app

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am developing new android app and i try to update status on my twitter account but automatically when launching some alarm but there are some strange , very stange !!
I set alarm to repeat every minute just to try but updating status is working fine one time and doesn't work next then working then doesn't and so on !!

What the reason of that knowing i am executing this code in alarm receiver but i login from another activity

this is my code :-

```
private Boolean updateTwitterStatus (String tweet) {
        Log.d("Tweet Text", "> " + tweet);
        String status = tweet;
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = twitterPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = twitterPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");

            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(access_token, access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            Log.d("token", "token : " + access_token);
            Log.d("secret", "secret : " + access_token_secret);

            // Update status
            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
            Log.e("response", "r :" + response);

            Log.d("Status", "> " + response.getText());
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // Error in updating status
            Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**logcat:-**

```
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188): Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1206f222
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1206f222], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.5}
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:162)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:98)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1965)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:264)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at com.engahmedphp.successquotes.AlarmReceiver.updateTwitterStatus(AlarmReceiver.java:207)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at com.engahmedphp.successquotes.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:163)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2816)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:126)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2088)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-02 23:08:59.020: W/System.err(4188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your log isn't full. solve of your problem should be on line up from now.

Also on Android never use.

```
     try {
     } catch(SomeException e)
        //this log isnt correct in android.util.Log method e 
        Log.d("Twitter Update Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Use for error loging [Log#e](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

also sometime e.printStackTrace() can be unwrited on your logcat. insted that please use

```
Log.e(TAG, "some message", e)
```